# Creating dynamic number of select based on entered textbox value

Tags: dynamic

I have a javascript which when a user enters a number to textbox,the script generates that much number of textboxes dynamically.But what i need is to create is select's instead of textboxes  with options retrieved from mysql database.
  the javascript for creating textbox is given below,

```
           <script type="text/javascript" >

       $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#stops").change(function () {

        var count = $("#holder input").size();
        var requested = parseInt($("#stops").val(), 10);
         if(requested == 0 && count > 0){
           location.reload();
           }
          $("#title").html("Stop Codes");

        if (requested > count) {
            for (i = count; i < requested; i++) {
                var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({
                    type: 'text',
                    name: 'text' + i,
                    placeholder: "Enter stop " +(i+1) +" airport code"
                });
                $("#holder").append($ctrl);

            }
        } else if (requested < count) {
            var x = requested - 1;
            $("#holder input:gt(" + x + ")").remove();
        }

    });
});
```

HTML generated textboxes here

```
  <td id="holder"></td>
```